# How to change/override rootDir/projectDir?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a big repo with some components.

```
\my_repo
|--modul1
|--modul2
|--modul3
|--modul4
|--modul5
|--modul6
...
```

When I want to build one component (modul1) using gradle which using another components (modul2 and modul3) I receive information like:

"Project with path ':module2/abc' could not be found in root project 'modul1'"

Is any possible to change/override rootDir/projectDir? I want to point to 'my_repo' while looking for another components?

I know that in ant it was possible by changing `basedir="../../"`. Is similar way to do in gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

The concept you would like to apply is referred to as *multi-project* or *multi-module builds*.

I suggest you read the official Gradle documentation for [authoring multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and/or work through the [create multi-project builds](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) guide.